# pass arg to High resolution timer callback

Tags: c, timer, callback, esp32, args

Hi i have a high resolution timer set like this.

```
esp_timer_handle_t timerHandle;
const esp_timer_create_args_t timerArgs={
    .callback = onTimer,
    .arg = NULL,
    .dispatch_method = ESP_TIMER_TASK,
    .name = "Measurement",
    .skip_unhandled_events = false
};
esp_timer_create(&timerArgs,&timerHandle);
```

I can use start and stop of timer with the next functions.

```
esp_timer_start_periodic(timerHandle,timeout_us);
    esp_timer_stop(timerHandle));
```

The onTimer callback function is this

```
void onTimer(void *args){
    // print a message from args, pass value on notification
}
```

From which function can i pass the info to the args of the callback function. Except making the variables extern or static and have them in the c file. I want to be able to pass the args.

Comment: I haven't used the Espressif functions, but it looks like you can probably set `timerArgs.arg` to point to a data structure of your choice, then access it from the pointer argument (you called it "`args`") passed to the callback.

Comment: :( , it was in front of my eyes. usually on tasks from freertos you are passing the args from there and as i stupid excuse i can say that i was looking only in that direction

Comment: You do not pass any parameters to the callback function. This parameter is used mainly to identify which handle it is if you have more than one handler for the same callback function.